# Creating population weighted spatial join of two layers with intersecting polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, spatial-join, population, combine

I have data where I sampled my outcome using a grid of 1-mile radii but my explanatory variables are at the census dissemination area level.

I would like to average my census dissemination area-level characteristics for each 1-mile radii. However, I would like this to be population weighted.

The census dissemination area level data has a variable that measures population.

Is there a way in arcGIS to create a population weighted average of the dissemination area level data for those DAs which intersect with each 1-mile sampling areas?

[image]